# "Background is null" but script works. How can I prevent the error?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a color changing background on my website. For that I have the following script (it will be used on two different HTML files):

```js
  const scroll = ( color, selector, offset ) => {
    const [red, green, blue] = color;
    const background = document.querySelector( selector );
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const y = 1 + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / offset;
        const [r, g, b] = [red/y, green/y, blue/y].map(Math.round);
        background.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
    });
  };
  scroll([255, 255, 255], '.background1', 250);
  scroll([0, 208, 255], '.background2', 500);
```

```css
.background1 {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
    
   
.i {
 height: 8000px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="background1"></div>
<p class="i">Scroll</p>
```

The script works but everytime I scroll down on my website my console is screaming because "Background is null". [Here's the picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I1BP.png)

I tried to set the script at the bottom of the body tag and I tried to surround it with a document.addEventListener('DOMCONTENTLOADED'):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  const scroll = ( color, selector, offset ) => {
    const [red, green, blue] = color;
    const background = document.querySelector( selector );
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const y = 1 + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / offset;
        const [r, g, b] = [red/y, green/y, blue/y].map(Math.round);
        background.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
    });
  };
  scroll([255, 255, 255], '.background1', 250);
  scroll([0, 208, 255], '.background2', 500);
});
```

It still didn't work.

I'm open for answers and tips for improvement.

Comment: A selector is used to select HTML elements. Since, for whatever reason, you’re keeping those a secret from us, you have not provided a [mre]. Please [edit] your post and do so. See [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212). Also, note that there is no such thing as a `DOMCONTENTLOADED` event. There is a [`DOMContentLoaded` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event), though.

Comment: "*The script works*" - are you sure there? In particular, does it work on both `.background1` and `.background2` or only on one of them?

Comment: @Bergi Ok, you're right. I swear I just used the same script in Firefox and it was working. But now it's not working anymore.

Comment: @dnos Pages? Bergi’s question was about elements, not pages. `document.querySelector(selector)` either returns an Element or `null`. You’re passing two values for `selector`, so you’re expecting two Elements. Do both elements exist? Easy to verify with `console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".background1, .background2").length === 2);`. Your snippet only shows `<div class="background1"></div>`, so where’s the element with `class="background2"`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I said pages because the elements are on two different HTML files. So they were both working like I said.

Answer (score 0):

> The script will be used on two different HTML files. The two elements are on two different HTML files.

Then you should also have two different scripts.

- On the page that has only the `<div class="background1"></div>`, you should only call `scroll([255, 255, 255], '.background1', 250);`
- On the page that has only the `<div class="background2"></div>`, you should only call `scroll([0, 208, 255], '.background2', 500);`

The definition of the `scroll` function you can put in a shared script that is included on both pages.

---

Alternatively, you can just make the `scroll` function do nothing if the selected element doesn't exist:

```
function scroll(color, selector, offset) {
    const [red, green, blue] = color;
    const background = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (background == null) return;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const y = 1 + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / offset;
        const [r, g, b] = [red/y, green/y, blue/y].map(Math.round);
        background.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
    });
}
```

I wouldn't recommend that though, it just makes potential failures even harder to debug.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought I can use it for more html files. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @dnos You could, but then you'll need to write the script in a way that makes it do different things on the different pages. This can depend on any number of things, easiest would be presence of the respective elements; but you should also plan what you would expect the script to do on a page where both elements were present.